# what is the meaning by 'species' of glycine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, proteins, amino-acids

The question ask for the species of the (i) glycine hydrochloride (ii) glycine titrated with NaOH. When they mentioned 'species', what did they mean by it?

Comment: Species here means the specific ionization state of glycine. Is it a neutral molecule or an ionized form? See the definition here: https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/CT01038

Answer (score 2):

The term species is used to describe a given type of atoms, molecules or ions. As a functional definition, a species is any atom, molecule or ion that could be part of a chemical reaction equation as reactant or product.

Here, it refers to the different protonation states of glycine, no matter whether anionic, neutral or cationic.